# Hi, i am trying to run the code "yarn create eth-app ./ but i am getting the following error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yarnpkg, yarn-v2, usedapp

success Installed "create-eth-app@1.8.2" with binaries:
- create-eth-app
'C:\Users\Shiloh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Users\Shiloh Madanha\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin\create-eth-app
Arguments: ./
Directory: C:\Users\Shiloh Madanha\Desktop\zimswap3.0
Output:

i have tried adding this path to the environment variables "C:\Users\Shiloh Madanha\Desktop\zimswap3.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove forward slash "/"

> `yarn create eth-app my-eth-app`
> If you want to create it in the same directory use dot only
> `yarn create eth-app .`

[Follow Official Document- click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-eth-app)

Comment: Hi, i did what you said and it did not work. Its giving me the same error

Comment: make sure you have installed  `yarn`  and `eth-app` . use this command to install for yarn `npm i yarn` and for eth-app  `npm i create-eth-app`